# Ios App menu icons and other icons are not visible when I archive but when I run the app icons and other things are working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hi i am new to ios development, i am a flutter developer currently working on a native ios app which was build by previous ios developer. I am facing one issue which is when i archive ipa and share it with testers at that time some icons and button text are shifted to the right or not visible but when i test it by running it on xcode everthing works as expected. Can some guide me if i need to change any config in deployment or so, As i am new to ios development I don't know what files are required to debug this issue, please ask for required files I will share those.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.I will attach some images for reference.

Archive ipa images:
[image: Text is shifted to the right]

[image: side bar icon and filter icon not visible]

Images of app when i run it from xcode:
[image: Text is in place]

[image: side bar icon and filter icon visible]

Thanks

I have tried adding resources in build phase of the target.
I have tried changing deployment targets and so on

Edit
I am adding code for side bar menu icon for reference. The image is a bit choppy I will update it as soon as I get hold of the mac system:
[image]

Comment: You probably have hard coded values but it is impossible to tell without the code. Stuff like expecting the screen to be a certain size and not accounting for smaller screens.

Comment: Hi I have added the side bar menu icon code for reference, all the images are in image catalog .xcassets file and that to is added in build phase of the target in copy resources. One more thing if the previous developer has not accounted for smaller size then it would not have worked at run time also.I have checked for both Debug and Release build